# Search Yahoo API geo.places with like operator

Tags: sql, yql, yahoo-api

I want to use the Yahoo API with the geo.places table. It really works great with single queries, but I want to list all city names which names BEGIN with the query text.

This is my query URL right now:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from geo.places where text = 'dallas'
```

And this is what I want:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from geo.places where text LIKE 'dallas%'
```

Is it possible? If yes, how exactly?

I can't find any useful information in the docs about this type of query regarding the geo.places table :(

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to perform a request that seems to fit what you are looking for:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from geo.places where text ='dallas*'
```