# Google Maps autocomplete Functionality from Apple Maps for Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, geolocation, apple-maps

I need to implement autocomplete Functionality for a City-Name Search in Objective C.

Basically at the Moment I would use the Google Maps autocomplete Functionality from here: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete

But I don't like displaying the powered by google - logo.

That's the reason why I'm asking here, is there a way to implement autocomplete Functionality using Apple Maps API or similar ?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: If you aren't showing maps you can do away with "Powered by Google" as they say it.

Comment: What about this ?: _When you display predictions from the Place Autocomplete service without a map, you must include the 'powered by Google' logo._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out - [Yahoo YQL console](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console).

There you can put queries like this - it gives you all places starting with `San`:

```
select * from geo.places where text="San%"
```

The resulting JSON / XML can act as data source to what you are trying to display for autocomplete results.

As I can see they allow up to some number of free queries for non-commercial use, and beyond that [they charge](https://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/#pricing). You may check it out [here](https://developer.yahoo.com/boss/geo/docs/requests-pf.html) and [here](https://developer.yahoo.com/boss/geo/docs/geo-faq.html).

Comment: That look's not to bad. But i haven't seen where i can get some Suggestions to implement a Autocomplete Functionality. Do you have ? Thanks again

Comment: Well it pretty much gives you data. It's up to you how you present that data. Maybe there is some syntax that can allow you to perform "like" searches instead of =, explore YQL and you will know.

Comment: Like does not work for _text_ but you can use a Query like that:
`select * from geo.places where text="san*"`. See here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285720/search-yahoo-api-geo-places-with-like-operator)

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to implement it yourself, you can use this service called 'Autocomplete as a Service' which is specifically written for these purposes. You can access it here - [www.aaas.io](http://aaas.io). It does support large datasets and you can apply filters as well. You just add your data and use the API URL in your autocomplete data source.

**Disclaimer:** I am founder of it. I will be happy to provide this service to you.